# Make linux tree bash script show files

Tags: bash, shell, tree

I created a shell script based on [a tree script](http://www.centerkey.com/tree/), however, i need a way to make said script show files as well as directories(By the way: i need the script to run on Mac OS X.)

Comment: Can you show a section of code that explains what you have and what you've tried to make it do what you want?

Answer (score 5):

Replace `ls -R | grep ':$'` with `find . -print`, and then adjust the `sed` command to reflect that names will not have ':' added and find will show the current directory:

```
find . -print | sed -e '/^\.$/d' -e 's/[^-][^\/]*\//--/g' -e 's/^/   /' -e 's/-/|/'
```